# Gradle: Depend on artifacts from ant legacy build

Tags: gradle, build, ant, dependencies, build.gradle

I am wondering how to declare a dependency on artifact produced by a legacy Ant build.

I have a Gradle build that consists of 2 modules: 'legacy' and 'backend'.
The 'legacy' module is quite old, requires an Ant to generate a 'legacy/dist' directory. I cannot convert this build to Gradle, unfortunately. This build takes a lot of time. For convenience, the Ant build is wrapped as a Gradle build.

The 'backend' module uses the 'war' plugin. It needs to package 'legacy/dist' directory into the war.

legacy/build.grade:

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
```

current backend/build.grade:

```
plugins {
    id 'war'
}

dependecies {
   ?
}

war {
    dependsOn ':legacy:dist'
    from('../legacy/dist')
}
```

This solution works, but has several drawbacks. To force Gradle to build 'legacy' before 'backend', I stated that the :backend:war task depends on the :legacy:dist task (not recommended). Every time I build backend, Gradle cannot know if legacy was build and calls :legacy:dist task, triggering unnecessarily the legacy build that takes a lot of time.

How should I declare on legacy/build.grade that it generates the dist directory and that the backend/build.grade depends on this dist directory? Without depending on tasks and without mentioning directory explicitly? I could figure out how to accomplish this from the documentation. Thanks.